# Dequeueing from RandomShuffleQueue does not reduce size

Tags: tensorflow

In order to train a model I have encapsulated my model in a class. 
I use a `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` to enqueue a list of filenames to. 
However when I dequeue the elements they get dequeued but the size of the queue does not reduce.

Following are more specific questions followed by the code snippet :

1. If I have only `5` images for example, but steps range upto 100, would this result in the `addfilenames` called repeatedly automatically ? It does not give me any error on dequeuing so I am thinking that it is getting called automatically.
2. Why the size of the `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` is not changing ? It remains constant.

   ```
   import os
   import time
   import functools
   import tensorflow as tf
   from Read_labelclsloc import readlabel


   def ReadTrain(traindir):
       # Returns a list of training images, their labels and a dictionay.
       # The dictionary maps label names to integer numbers.                                                                    
       return trainimgs, trainlbls, classdict


   def ReadVal(valdir, classdict):
      # Reads the validation image labels.
      # Returns a dictionary with filenames as keys and 
      # corresponding labels as values.
       return valdict

   def lazy_property(function):
     # Just a decorator to make sure that on repeated calls to 
     # member functions, ops don't get created repeatedly.
     # Acknowledgements : https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/
       attribute= '_cache_' + function.__name__
       @property
       @functools.wraps(function)
       def decorator(self):
           if not hasattr(self, attribute):
               setattr(self, attribute, function(self))
           return getattr(self, attribute)

       return decorator    

   class ModelInitial:

       def __init__(self, traindir, valdir):
           self.graph
           self.traindir = traindir
           self.valdir = valdir
           self.traininginfo()
           self.epoch = 0



       def traininginfo(self):
           self.trainimgs, self.trainlbls, self.classdict = ReadTrain(self.traindir)
           self.valdict = ReadVal(self.valdir, self.classdict)
           with self.graph.as_default():
               self.trainimgs_tensor = tf.constant(self.trainimgs)
               self.trainlbls_tensor = tf.constant(self.trainlbls, dtype=tf.uint16)
               self.trainimgs_dict = {}
               self.trainimgs_dict["ImageFile"] = self.trainimgs_tensor
           return None

       @lazy_property
       def graph(self):
           g = tf.Graph()
           with g.as_default():
              # Layer definitions go here 
           return g


       @lazy_property
       def addfilenames (self):
      # This is the function where filenames are pushed to a RandomShuffleQueue
           filename_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=len(self.trainimgs), min_after_dequeue=0,\
                                                  dtypes=[tf.string], names=["ImageFile"],\
                                                  seed=0, name="filename_queue")

           sz_op = filename_queue.size()

           dq_op = filename_queue.dequeue()

           enq_op = filename_queue.enqueue_many(self.trainimgs_dict)
           return filename_queue, enq_op, sz_op, dq_op

       def Train(self):
       # The function for training.
       # I have not written the training part yet.
       # Still struggling with preprocessing 
           with self.graph.as_default():
               filename_q, filename_enqueue_op, sz_op, dq_op= self.addfilenames

               qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(filename_q, [filename_enqueue_op])
               filename_dequeue_op = filename_q.dequeue()
               init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

           sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
           sess.run(init_op)
           coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
           enq_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
           counter = 0
           for step in range(100):
               print(sess.run(dq_op["ImageFile"]))
               print("Epoch = %d "%(self.epoch))
               print("size = %d"%(sess.run(sz_op)))
               counter+=1

           names = [n.name for n in self.graph.as_graph_def().node]
           coord.request_stop()
           coord.join(enq_threads)
           print("Counter = %d"%(counter))
           return None





   if __name__ == "__main__":
       modeltrain = ModelInitial(<Path to training images>,\
                                       <Path to validation images>)
       a = modeltrain.graph
       print(a)
       modeltrain.Train()
       print("Success")
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery is caused by the [`tf.train.QueueRunner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/QueueRunner) that you created for the queue, which causes it to be filled in the background.

1. The following lines cause a background "queue runner" thread to be created:

   ```
   qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(filename_q, [filename_enqueue_op])
   # ... 
   enq_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
   ```

   This thread calls `filename_enqueue_op` in a loop, which causes the queue to be filled up as you remove elements from it.
2. The background thread from step 1 will almost always have a pending enqueue operation (`filename_enqueue_op`) on the queue. This means that after you dequeue a filename, the pending enqueue will run add fill the queue back up to capacity. (Technically there is a race condition here and you could see a size of `capacity - 1`, but this is quite unlikely).

Comment: Thanks. I was also expecting this. I find `tf.train.QueueRunner` to be quite restrictive. I am compelled to use a single `enqueue_op`. I cannot put a general function in there. I want to be able to keep a strict track of the particular `epoch` by incrementing the `epoch` as soon as one full `enqueue_many` is over. How can I achieve it ? Unfortunately i don't see any of that functionality in `QueueRunner` yet. If it is, then it is not properly documented. Dataset handling and preprocessing right now is the biggest headache in TensorFlow. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Ujjwal, queuerunner logic is quite small, I sometimes find it useful to not use queue runners and run enqueue operations myself from separate Python thread. That gives more control, see https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/tree/master/queues_talk for some explanations

Comment: Ya. I finally found the solution using a class structure and threading module. It is clearer and gives more control than QueueRunner. Infact, for complex preprocessing, QueueRunners prove rather useless. On Github i saw that a new input pipeline is proposed for version 2.0 .Seriously, tensorflow needs an overhaul with input pipeline.